# CakePHP Auth - Allow access to non-logged in users, but then restrict based on other criteria

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.3

I will get straight into this.

I have users, with the property of privacy. Privacy can either be public or private.
I want to be able to allow non-logged in users to be able to view another user, as long as the other user is public, and of course if they are private check if that user is the current user.

I can not think of the best way to do it, because isAuthorized is only called for logged in users, and I can not just allow the action as then isAuthorized is not called at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would just do the checks you describe in your action, then either redirect away or throw an exception if the check fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to prepend some logic in your controller action to verify if the profile is public or private and if it's private, wheter or not the currently logged in user (if any) is the owner of the profile. Something like this should do the trick:

```php
// app/Controller/UsersController.php
public function view($id) {
    // Check the privacy setting
    if ($this->User->isPrivate($id)) {
        // Private profile, check if user is logged in and id matches
        if (empty($this->Auth->user()) || $this->Auth->user('id') != $id) {
            // User is either not logged in or not the person we want to view
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                // Inspired by Cartman rage... you might want to change it ;-)
                __('No kitty, this is my profile!')
            );
            // Redirect the user back to our index action (or anywhere else)
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

And make sure to create the isPrivate checking method in your model as well:

```php
// app/Model/User.php
public function isPrivate($id) {
    $privacy = $this->field('privacy', array('id' => $id));
    if ($privacy == 'private') {
        // This is a private profile
        return true;
    }

    // This is a public profile
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What are the issues you are having with it?

Comment: only minor things like the use of empty with an argument from a returning method. And optimisation.